# Writing a Shell Script that runs my program with inputs

Tags: c++, linux, bash, shell

Ok so I created my own shell, and I've tested it plenty on my own, but I need shell scripts that will run it and test it.

I've create a script which consist of this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "ls && echo dog" | ./a.out
```

However, all it does is print the command prompt "$" infinitely, and I have to force quit the program. therefore I am pretty sure my program does not like my script lol. My program works by using getline to capture the user input until they push <enter> and the boost library to tokenize the string and look for connector e.g "||" "&&" ";" and  and so on, then run the commands. All of this is done in a while loop that loops until the user types exit and I close my program. Being as I am new to writing scripts I am sure I probably am not writing my script in the best of manners. I created a simple program to ask for your age and then output it and this script method works for that, but being as my shell isn't as simple I am not surprised this scrip doesn't seem to work.

```
string user_input;
bool good = true;
typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > tokenizer;

    while(good){
        //command prompt
        cout << "$ "; 

        //read in user input
        getline(cin, user_input);

        //tokenize user input
        tokenizer tok(user_input);
        //parse and execute commands inputed by user in string 
        //only exit while loop if user command is <exit> good = false    
    }
```

my shell works if I execute the program normally and I enter inputs into the program what I need is a shell script that I can use to run and test the program for me. Ex. if I type  ./script.sh in the standard linux shell it will run my script which will then execute my a.out and then test my own shell with a variety of commands Examples being ls echo ...

Comment: It's not possible to analyze a problem and provide useful results with any reliability when you've given us zero code to analyze. Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1):

You should exit the shell when you reach EOF (End Of File). Getline while return -1 in that case. 
I can't think of any other advice as you didn't provide any code, but this might resolve the infinite loop issue.